# Как изменить статик файлы в django?

Tags: python, django

закинул статик-файлы в ../project/assets/, затем прописал команду collectsatic, они добавились все в ../project/static/, теперь когда я редактирую style.css, он не изменяется, пробовал редактировать и там и там. Как их теперь изменять нормально?  Вряд-ли же после каждого изменения нужно будет опять жать collectstatic
Хотя и после команды collectstatic ничего не меняется, хотя оба файла изменились. Я так понимаю он хранит копии статик-файлов по какому-то своему локальному пути, когда создаешь локальный сервер

Comment: была похожая проблема. Решал колдовством. Я просто открывал css файл в браузере и обновлял его

Comment: Команда collectstatic копирует статику из папок Django-приложений и STATICFILES_DIRS в папку STATIC_ROOT. Разберитесь, что откуда копируется, и там и редактируйте

Comment: И да, использовать команду collectstatic в окружении для разработки не надо, она только для продакшена, чтобы раздавать статику веб-сервером.

Comment: А ещё, возможно, вы банально забыли почистить кэш браузера

Comment: @andreymal, я не понимаю как тут отметить ответ, но да, ты был правл, нужно было банально нажать ctrl+f5

Answer (score 1):

@andreymal, да все верно, оказалось просто надо было сбросить кэш ( обновлять страницу через ctrl + f5)